# Retrofit Gson Deserialization. Is it needed to every response?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I got a json response from news api that looks like this

```
status": "ok",
"totalResults": 38,
"articles": [{
       "author": "Zoe Christen Jones",
       "title": "Skylar Mack, American teen jailed for violating quarantine in Cayman 
        Islands, gets reduced sentence - CBS News",
       "description": "Skylar Mack, ..."
}]
```

Usually I do make some classes that represent every response from it

```
data class NewsResponse(
        @SerializedName("status") var status: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("totalResult") var total: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("articles") var articles: List<Articles> = emptyList()
)

data class Articles(
        @SerializedName("author") var author: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("title") var title: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("description") var url: String? = null)
```

But,let's say I just want to grab `articles` from root response, annotate it like this

```
data class NewsResponse(
            @SerializedName("articles") var articles: List<Articles> = emptyList()
    )
```

Is it a good practice to just ommit unnecesarry response that I dont want to?, in this case I dont want to grab `status` and `totalResponse`.

Comment: I think it is good practice to only consume what you really need. Maybe you have to configure your Deserializer to not complain about unknown fields (some might throw an exception).

Comment: So you said that if I do not dezerialize every responses they could throw an exception?

Comment: Some Deserializer maybe throw an exception like `UnknownProperty` to let you know there is more data available. But this is something you need to look up in the documentation (or try out) with the Deserializer you are using.